# Using "SentOnBehalfOf" With Exchange EWS

Tags: c#, soap, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I've been tasked with writing a simple application to send emails using EWS.

I've been following the example set forth here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn789003(v=exchg.150).aspx

using our exchange server address.  Using this example everything is going just peachy until I attempt to send a message from a second mailbox I have access to.  I am able to send messages from my own inbox without any difficulty.

I've modified the example a bit, but the essential portion is the text string representing the soap request.  In that string I've attempted to add:

```
<t:Sender>
    <t:Mailbox>
        <t:EmailAddress>AltMailboxAddress@server.com</t:EmailAddress>
    </t:Mailbox>
</t:Sender>
```

Which sends the message, but it still appears to the recipient that it came from me.  I've also tried:

```
<t:From>
    <t:Mailbox>
        <t:EmailAddress>AltMailboxAddress@server.com</t:EmailAddress>
    </t:Mailbox>
</t:From>
```

Which returns a 500 internal server error.

I can't help but feel that I'm using the wrong tag.  I do have access to this mailbox through Outlook, it shows up as a second mailbox under my profile.  Additionally, I've been able to send messages through this account by automating Outlook and using the "SentOnBehalfOf" property of the MailItem object, but no dice here.

We'd really like to get away from automating Outlook to send messages if we can, we've run into an issue or two lately, and this looks like it might be the last major hurdle to clear.

Thanks!

EDIT:  Ok, I see that the sender tag is used for a "send on behalf of" type operation, but this still isn't quite working....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Send On Behalf of another user in EWS you don't need to set the Sender Property what you need to do is use the SentItems Folder in the SavedItemFolderId of the user you want to send on behalf of and EWS will do the rest eg

```
 <soap:Header>
 <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1" />
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
  <m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SendAndSaveCopy">
    <m:SavedItemFolderId>
      <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="sentitems">
        <t:Mailbox>
          <t:EmailAddress>SendingonBehalf@domain.onmicrosoft.com</t:EmailAddress>
        </t:Mailbox>
      </t:DistinguishedFolderId>
    </m:SavedItemFolderId>
    <m:Items>
      <t:Message>
        <t:Subject>this is a test</t:Subject>
        <t:ToRecipients>
          <t:Mailbox>
            <t:EmailAddress>recip@domain.onmicrosoft.com</t:EmailAddress>
          </t:Mailbox>
        </t:ToRecipients>
      </t:Message>
    </m:Items>
  </m:CreateItem>
</soap:Body>
```

You can check to make sure the user has permission using Get-Mailbox and look at the GrantSendOnBehalfTo property

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thank you!  This helped, but wasn't quite the whole solution.  I don't know if it's just the way our server is set up or what, but when I sent a message using the xml you've provided it still appeared as coming from my default mailbox.  Curiously, it did not show up in either my own or the alt mailbox sent items folder either.  However, using this xml and adding the `From` element did the trick.  I just thought I'd make a note of that and pass it along to you.  I initially tried pairing this with the sender tag, which produced an error.

Comment: One other comment.  Even with this method working when paired with use of the from element the sent item does not appear in the sent items folder.  Not quite the end of the world, but not exactly perfect either.  If you have any suggestions there, let me know!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It's the `From` element that you need ([ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa581049(v=exchg.150).aspx)):

> 'This element is used for "send on behalf of" e-mails.'

I'm not sure but I think if you have Send As permissions then the email will be sent *As* the from address, and if you only have Send On Behalf Of permissions the email will be sent with that instead.

Specifying the `SavedItemFolderId` says where to put the emails but you can save them to the From mailbox OR save to the sender mailbox. Of course you need permissions to the appropriate folder to save them there.

If you're not already, it's easiest to interact with EWS via the Managed API rather than making web services calls directly with XML.